# Error: Failed to start Node process

Tags: asp.net-core

How to generate pdf? I am trying node service but it is not working. I have visual studio 2015 Microsoft.NETCore.App:1.0.1

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
        {
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            var htmlContent = await hc.GetStringAsync($"http://{Request.Host}/report.html");
            var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("./pdf", htmlContent);

            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-filename", "report.pdf");
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-filename");
            HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            return new ContentResult();
        }
```

[image]